# How to resolve baseurl issue with CentOS-Base.repo on Linux (Centos 6.7) to run "yum install ftp"

Tags: centos, yum

I am working in installing FTP and found this issue that I am unable to install yum. Referred many places and did `yum clean all` and configured CentOs-Base.repo to have vault.centos.org as baseurl for -Base. I am still unable to install ftp using yum. I get the below error:

```
[root@ts-htn-01 yum.repos.d]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Update Process
Repository base is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository updates is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository extras is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository centosplus is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository contrib is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository '-dc' is missing name in configuration, using id
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 7 - "couldn't connect to host"
https://vault.centos.org/6.7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - "couldn't connect to host"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again
[root@ts-htn-01 yum.repos.d]#
```

My http service is running:

```
[root@ts-htn-01 yum.repos.d]# service httpd status
httpd (pid  6650) is running...
[root@ts-htn-01 yum.repos.d]#
```

My ping to vault.centos.org and mirrorlist.centos.org is working fine. Should I add this to host connections..? If yes, please let me know how. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with clear `yum` cache and again update

Comment: @RomeoNinov, Ty.. could you please tell me how to clear yum cache..? Should I save anything before clearing..? Will I lose any file configurations.....?

Comment: `yum clean all`. And no, you will not loose anything except yum cache and downloaded files.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I cleared the cache using the command `yum clean all` and still seeing the issue. Could you help...?

Comment: try something like: `yum --disableplugin=fastestmirror update`

Comment: @RomeoNinov still getting the same error...